# Can I use 'measurable' to stress that the concept must have numeric quantity?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I am describing certain self-organization technique, which has the concept of **goals** (duh). These goals must manifest themselves in certain quantities (e.g. 'go outside for **30 minutes**', 'read **10 pages**' etc), never as simply done/not done items (e.g. 'take out the trash' would not be an acceptable goal).

Can I say, "the goals must be measurable"? Does measurability imply there is a number, or yes/no questions can still be considered measurable? Is there a better single word describing this constraint? (I thought of *countable*, but it just doesn't sound right).

Comment: Yes, you can! e.g. **Your goals must be measurable, with identifiable steps that give you the ability to see your progress step by step**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're possibly after "**quantifiable**".

You can google an incredible number of [examples](https://planleft.com/quantifiable-marketing-measuring-your-business-success), particularly in the [business-jargon](http://www.trojanmice.com/randomjargongenerator.htm) sense.

Really I think "measurable" is fine, also.  (I can't see how you could measure a quantifiable difference between such word choices.)

Comment: Indeed, the difference seems moot. A common buzz in management speak is SMART goals, where the M stands for, yes, _measurable_.

Comment: outstanding observation!

Comment: Nice suggestion, although it sounds a tad too businessy. I'd like to keep my copy friendly, so if "measurable" is fine, I'll probably go with that. Especially since there is already a "measure progress in _____" prompt in my app.

Comment: I agree with quantifiable being a good option, if it is not the best but I'd suggest that you revise your opinion on "measurable" being fine too. The two may often be but are not always synonymous. Measurable most literally means able to be measured and this ignores *comparative* forms of measure like when you hold your fingers close together and say "this small", "as tall as a tree" as far as the eye can see, a hair's breadth apart, at arm's length, et cetera. In fact, I believe the *true* base unit of any measurement system is usually a unit of comparison. An inch is three barley corns long

Comment: **Quantifiable** -- great.  *Measurable* -- not as precise.  Think of 0-1 variables, such as *trash taken out: yes/no*.